# How to display blank textbox instead of zero in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

**Im using spring mvc with hibernate validator. My problem is that when the integer value is zero it displays 0 in my textbox. I want to display only empty string. how to do it?**

**In my JSP:**

```
<form:form action ="processForm" modelAttribute="customer" >
...
...
Free Passes: <form:input path="freePasses"/>
<form:errors path="freePasses" cssClass="error" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form:form>
```

**My customer class:**

```
public class Customer {
...
private int freePasses;
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public class CustomerController {
@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customer",new Customer());
    return "customer-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer cust,
        BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer-form";
    } else {
        return "customer-confirmation";
    }
}
}
```

**When Form is getting loaded I want see empty in Free Passes field not zero.**

[Result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoSJs.png)

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9EGY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are using primitive type `int` which defaults to 0.

> private int freePasses;

I would advise to use Wrapper `Integer` instead this would solve your issue.

> private Integer freePasses;

*NOTE : Do not forget to regenerate the getter/setters once you change from int to Integer*

Answer (score 0):

Use `<c:if>` JSP JSTL(java standard tag library) if condition tag and check condition for value 0 and set value to "" empty string like below.

```
<c:if test = "${customer.freePasses == 0}">
   //put text area with empty string
</c:if>
```

Refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm